# Helicon Ape build 0098: "Access to the path is denied" when enabling licenses

Tags: helicontech

I just upgraded Helicon Ape to the latest build 0098. Then I opened the Helicon Ape Manager, went to "Help" -> "License Manager", selected one of my sites and chose "Enable free license". This message came up: **"Access to the path is denied"**.

I made sure that I had free licenses available before I tried to enable it on that specific site. I also granted rights to "Everyone" in the security-settings of the website folder. It is also possible to explore the website folder in the Helicon Ape Manager.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem or have any idea what this could be?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install Full or Free version?
What is your Windows version?
And why don't we continue looking into the problem on Helicon Tech helpdesk: http://support.helicontech.com/helpdesk/

Comment: Free version on Windows 7. Thanks for the advice - I just submitted a ticket on HeliconTech Helpdesk. I will post the answer here if I get it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it just stopped working after a windows update.  I upgraded to version 3.1.0.105 and followed the troubleshooting steps. I had to add `read` & `list folder` permissions for my `IIS_USERS` group to the `Helicon` folder in `program files(x86)`.

This still didn't fix it.  So I played with a  few settings and at some-point in the process I removed .Net Framework v2.0xxxx from the app pool configuration (set it to No Managed Code.)  After trying the debugger and everything else I could think of I decided to start over.

I uninstalled helicon.  Reinstalled it from scratch.  I re-added the IIS_USERS permissions to the Helicon application folder in Program Files (x86).  And it still didn't work.  Then I re-routed the application pool through .net and sure enough everything worked... which makes sense since APE is a .net application and uses .net hooks into iis.

Anyway, after doing all of that it is now working for me.